# Analyzing Segmentation fault Core Dump (gdb)

Tags: c, linux, gdb, coredump

I am getting following segmentation faults while running a Linux based application on imax6q custom hardware design. I backtraced the core dump using Linux GDB and following you can see those core dumps.

The kernel I'm using - Linux-boundary 4.1.15

Seg fault Core dump 1

```
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0 gcoTEXTURE_BindTextureEx (Texture=0x263c6c4, Target=Target@entry=0, 
Sampler=1, Sampler@entry=0, Info=Info@entry=0x23f0708, 
textureLayer=textureLayer@entry=0)
at gc_hal_user_texture.c:3804
3804 gc_hal_user_texture.c: No such file or directory.
```

Seg fault Core dump 2

```
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0 _SetFenceCtx (fence=0x5c30d6c, head=0x5c2ab74) at 
gc_hal_user_hardware.c:5752
5752 gc_hal_user_hardware.c: No such file or directory.
```

1) Those core dumps are directed to following source files. But I couldn't find those file in the above Linux-boundary 4.1.15 kernel build. What are they referring to? To overcome this problem what do you suggest?

```
gc_hal_user_texture.c
gc_hal_user_hardware.c
src/glcore/gc_es_draw.c:943
src/glcore/gc_es_api.c:399
```

2) I could find a file called gc_hal_kernel_hardware.c in my kernel build. So is this the file the gdb back traced log is pointing out? Do you have any idea of this kind of segmentation faults?

Comment: Take the directory you found `gc_hal_kernel_hardware.c` in and use it in the `dir` command directly in GDB like so: `dir theDirectory`

Comment: Run the gdb `bt` command and look at the part of the stack that includes code that you wrote (or that you're in a position to fix).

Answer (score 2):

Read [documentation of `gdb`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/), notably [9.5 Specifying Source Directories](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Source-Path.html). Since you have a `core` dump it is some [user-space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_space) application which crashes (not the [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system)); the kernel is supposed to never crash, and when it unfortunately does, you could have a frozen system). See also [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html). Your `gc_hal_user_texture.c` belongs to that crashing [application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_software), or to some [library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)) used by it.

You might use [file(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/file.1.html) to find out which program produces that `core`. Run `file core`. See also [core(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html) & [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html).

Be sure to [compile](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) that program with [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) debug info and all warnings, so `gcc -g -Wall -Wextra`

Read [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) to understand the principles (and difference between user-space code and operating system kernel code).

> But I couldn't find those file in the above Linux-boundary 4.1.15 kernel build. What are they referring to?

These `gc_hal_user_texture.c` ... `src/glcore/gc_es_api.c` files refer to some application or library source code (of course they are not kernel source files).